# Show that the behavior of $f$ for $z \rightarrow \infty$ is described by exactly one of the following three cases

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $K \subseteq \mathbb C$ be compact and $f: \mathbb C\setminus K$ holomorphic. Show that the behavior of $f$ for $z \rightarrow \infty$ is described by exactly one of the following three cases:

a) there is one $w_0$ $\in \mathbb C$ such that $f(z) \rightarrow w_0, z \rightarrow \infty$.

b) there is one $a$ $\in \mathbb C \setminus \left\{0\right\}$  such that $\frac{f(z)}{az^m} \rightarrow 1, $ $z$ $\rightarrow$  $\infty$.

c) to each $w \in \mathbb C$ there is $z_n \rightarrow \infty$ with $f(z_n) \rightarrow w$

---

My idea so far: I think I have to show that all these claims are true, that a)-c) are true. but I am not sure how to begin.

Comment: How can all of them be true if you’re asked to show that exactly one holds?

Comment: *Hint:* Look up “isolated singularity” (which can be removable, a pole, or essential).

Comment: oh sorry youre right

Comment: the easy way to do it is to enclose $K$ in a disc centered at the origin of say radius $R$ and then take $g(w)=f(R/w), |w|<R$ and then the behavior of $f$ at infinity is the same as the behavior of $g$ at zero which is now an isolated singularity so covered by the usual three cases which correspond to the three cases above

Answer (score 0):

Hint. If $K\subset D(0,R)$, then $f$ can be expressed as a Laurent series
of the form:
$$
f(z)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}a_kz^k+\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k
$$

Case I. If $a_k=0$, for every $k>0$, then $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=a_0$.

Case II. If $a_k=0$, for every $k>n$, and $a_n\ne 0$, then
$$\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{f(z)}{z^n}=a_n$$

Case III. If $a_k\ne 0$, for infinitely many positive integers $k$, then $f[A_{r,\infty}]$ is dense in $\mathbb C$, for every $r>R$, where
$$
A_{r,\infty}=\{z\in\mathbb C: |z|>r\}.
$$